# Accessing multiple rows with Eloquent ORM Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a table with the following data and I'm trying to grab all the rows with the type of "iphones" and pass them to an object

```
 $catagories = array(

                        array(
                            'item' => 'iphone 4s',
                            'type' => 'iphones',
                            'cost' => '255'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'item' => 'iphone 5s',
                            'type' => 'iphones',
                            'cost' => '255'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'item' => 'iphone 3g',
                            'type' => 'iphones',
                            'cost' => '255'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'item' => 'iphone 3gs',
                            'type' => 'iphones',
                            'cost' => '255'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'item' => 'iphone 6',
                            'type' => 'iphones',
                            'cost' => '255'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'item' => 'htc one x',
                            'type' => 'phones',
                            'cost' => '255'
                        ),
```

I've tried these following lines of code individually and none of them worked :(

```
                //Find all items where type "iphone" and create Object
                // $item = DB::table('Catagories')->where('type', $item)->first();
                // $item = DB::table('Catagories')->where('type', $item);
                // $item = DB::table('Catagories')->select('type', $item)->get();
                // $roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title', 'name');

$item = iphones;
$item = DB::table('Catagories')->where('type', $item);
```

How can I efficiently access this data and send it to a view?
I need to get all the properties the item with the type of iphones and echo in a view using foreach.

Comment: Your table is called `Catagories` (case sensitive)?

Comment: `none of them worked` means nothing. Paste the errors or describe what happens there.